# Extend Application Class for ParseUser

Tags: java, android, serialization, parse-platform, singleton

I would like to extend my `Application` class in order to globally access the logged in `ParseUser` without repeatedly calling `.getCurrentUser()` and accessing it's fields in every activity.

Currently my `Application` class is already extended to initialize Parse and ParseFacebookUtils. As per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238049/send-not-serializable-data-to-new-activity%20/), it says to make an instance of the `ParseUser` in the `Application` class however I'm not sure how to do so.

Note: I do not want to use intents as ParseUser is not serializable.

Thank you for your help. I can't see the relevance for code inclusion but please ask if you require any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a Singleton to solve my problem. I have extended the Application class to initialize a Singleton so that an instance of this Singleton exists whether an activity is destroyed or othewise. I can access this instance via any activity and as such access all the fields of the current ParseUser.

// *Application Class*

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Parse.initialize(this, "redacted", "redacted");
        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);
        initSingleton();
    }

    protected void initSingleton() {
        ParseUserSingleton.initInstance();
    }
}
```

// *Singleton Class*

```
public class ParseUserSingleton {

    private static ParseUserSingleton instance;

    public ParseUser user;
    public HashMap<String, String> userFields = new HashMap<>();

    public static void initInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            // Create the instance
            instance = new ParseUserSingleton();
        }
    }

    public static ParseUserSingleton getInstance() {
        // Return the instance
        return instance;
    }

    private ParseUserSingleton() {
        // Constructor hidden because this is a singleton
    }

    public void customSingletonMethod() {
        try {
            user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().fetch();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        userFields.put("name", user.get("availability").toString());
        // repeat for other fields
    }
}
```

// *Activity access*

```
ParseUserSingleton.getInstance().customSingletonMethod();
userHashMap = ParseUserSingleton.getInstance().userFields;
```

Answer (score 0):

Method `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` doesn't perform any network operations so it can't block UI. Also it is static, so by some means it already gives you global access.

I think it is not the best idea to duplicate it's value somewhere and it could cause bugs

Comment: Not sure why I believed it blocked the UI. I am certainly under the impression that calling `.getCurrentUser()` for each activity/fragment can't be efficient. Is that what you're recommending?

Comment: Parse SDK provides a bunch of accessors for some state variables such as `getCurrentUser()`, `getCurrentInstallation()` and more, which is designed to provide current local representation of these fields and they are  static so you can access them from anywhere inside your App and you don't need to store it in some additional place, cause values in the ParseUser for example may change, but your copy may not know about it. 
I always call `getCurrentUser()` in order to get most actual representation of ParseUser. Sometimes with `ParseUser.fetch()` before if changes was made remotely

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is have 2 attributes in the existing application class.

1. isLoggedIn(boolean) - initialise it as false
2. user(ParseUser)

And place getters and setters.

When the user logs into the system you can set the isLoggedIn to true and set the user as well in the loginActivity. Suppose extended Application class is MyApplication.

`((MyApplication)getApplication).setIsLoggedIn(true)` 
`((MyApplication)getApplication).setUser(parseUser)` .

After that you can in other activities you can simply check the isLoggedIn boolean value and do the necessary actions.

You can retrieve the set user by
`ParseUser currentUser = ((MyApplication)getApplication).getUser()`

Hope this helps.